# gstreamer videomixer2 cpu usage 164%. Any solution to decrease

Tags: python, gstreamer

As a part of my project, I will have to synchronize 2 videos. Since i am implementing it in python, i started using gstreamer.

My pipeline looks like this

filesrc -> decoder-> queuev -> videobox

filesrc-1 -> decoder-> queuev1 -> videobox1

both of these videobox is joined to mixer like this

[videobox 1 and 2 ] -> mixer -> ffmpegcolorspace ->videosink

All of them in a single pipeline.

But problem here is when i run the code , i get 174% cpu usage which i think is not really optimized. Is there any way to reduce this? because even if i simply run 3 videos in parallel pipelines i get 14% cpu usage.

I am also uploading part of my code here.

```
self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline('pipleline')
self.filesrc = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc")

self.filesrc.set_property('location', videoloc1)
self.pipeline.add(self.filesrc)

self.decode = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin2", "decode")
self.pipeline.add(self.decode)

self.queuev = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "queuev")
self.pipeline.add(self.queuev)

self.video = gst.element_factory_make("autovideosink", "video")
self.pipeline.add(self.video)

self.filesrc_2 = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc2")
self.filesrc_2.set_property('location', videoloc2) 
self.pipeline.add(self.filesrc_2)

self.decode_2 = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin2", "decode_2")
self.pipeline.add(self.decode_2)

self.queuev_2 = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "queuev_2")
self.pipeline.add(self.queuev_2)

self.mixer = gst.element_factory_make("videomixer2", "mixer")
self.pipeline.add(self.mixer)

self.videobox_1 = gst.element_factory_make("videobox", "videobox_1")
self.pipeline.add(self.videobox_1)

self.videobox_2 = gst.element_factory_make("videobox", "videobox_2")
self.pipeline.add(self.videobox_2)

self.ffmpeg1 = gst.element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace", "ffmpeg1")
self.pipeline.add(self.ffmpeg1)

gst.element_link_many(self.filesrc,self.decode)
gst.element_link_many(self.filesrc_2,self.decode_2)  
gst.element_link_many(self.queuev,self.videobox_1,self.mixer,self.ffmpeg1,self.video)                                          
gst.element_link_many(self.queuev_2,self.videobox_2,self.mixer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Videomixer is using the cpu to mix videos. Anyway, in oder to know, run a profiler (oprofile, sysprof) to see what code is using the most cpu. Also you did not said anything on the resolutions and colorspaces involved and the hardware you run this on. Thus it is hard to say wheter is is unexpectedly slow.
Finally, you don#t need to mix videos to sync them, you can just run them in a single pipeline. It is up to your application to e.g. render into separate drawing areas in your window or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streamsynchronizer https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-streamsynchronizer.html